Lifetime break out from block?
struct container<'x> {
    value: &'x i32,
}

impl<'x> container<'x> {
    fn f(&'x mut self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let v = 1;
    let mut a = container{value: &v}; // 'a----------+
    { //                                             |
        let a1 = & mut a; //'b---------------------+ |
        a1.f(); //                                 | |
        //end--------------------------------------+ |
    } //                                             |
    //end--------------------------------------------+
    let p = & mut a; // suppose to be 'c but 'b break out from block?
}

This won't compile with error: cannot borrow 'a' as mutable more than once at a time.
And first borrow here: let a1 = & mut a; which is in the block. The lifetime should end already but somewhere it breaks out?
As follow up to Pavlo Myroniuk's answer, consider:
fn i32_f<'a>(k: &'a mut i32) {}

fn main() {
    let mut v:i32 = 1;
    let mut i32_a = &mut v;
    { //                                             |
        let i32_a1 = & mut i32_a; //'b-------------+ |
        i32_f(i32_a1);  //                         | |
        //end--------------------------------------+ |
    } //                                             |
    //end--------------------------------------------+
    let i32_p = & mut i32_a; // works
}

If a reference of container can lives after the block, why can't a reference of i32 do so? It seems break the consistency of what lifetime is.

Remove the lifetime in the declaration of f, i.e.: fn f (&mut self) {}

@Jmb I know this work, but it doesn't explain the error I found.

I'm pretty sure there's a duplicate somewhere, but the TLDR is that by giving an explicit 'x lifetime to &mut self you're linking the lifetime of the mutable borrow done by calling f to the container<'x> lifetime. I.e. you're telling the compiler that they are the same.

Let's go through your code part by part.
First one:
struct container<'x> {
    value: &'x i32,
}

The code above means that &i32 must live at least as long as container lives.
impl<'x> container<'x> {
    fn f(&'x mut self) {}
}

Here you specified the same lifetime parameter 'x for the command lifetime and for the f method parameter lifetime. Basically, you say that mutable reference to self must live at least as long as the inner &i32 lives (or in other words, as long as the container lives).
And this is why it is still mutably borrowed even after the end of the block.
When you write code like this:
impl<'x> container<'x> {
    fn f(&mut self) {}
}

then a new lifetime will be assigned to the &mut self and the code will compile. For the compiler, the code above looks like this:
impl<'x> container<'x> {
    fn f<'b>(&'b mut self) {}
}


I understand f() is live with container.value and/or the container itself. But the borrowed reference a1 (which is type &mut container) should ends as long as block ends. Is this correct?

Well yes, but actually no. You are right that the reference a1 will drop at the block's end, but on the other side, you bind it to the 'x lifetime. Rust just doesn't allow to break lifetime rules. Yes, in such a small example it is possible to track such situations and allow to break some lifetime rules, but not in every one. So, Rust doesn't allow violating the lifetimes even if it theoretically will not break the execution.
